# No puedo quitar disabled desde TS

Tags: angular, typescript

cuando pongo la propiedad disabled desde HTML, luego con removeAttribute mediante getElementById, no puedo eliminarla, el problema está en que la propiedad la estoy aplicando a un mat-checkbox de material y creo que no lo elimina por eso, adjunto codigo

```
<mat-checkbox disabled class="str fs bal" color="warn" id="{{'Balance'+i}}">
<mat-checkbox disabled class="str fs mov" color="warn" id{{'Movements'+i}}">



var balance = document.getElementById('Balance' + casilla);
var movements = document.getElementById('Movements' + casilla);
balance.removeAttribute('disabled');
movements.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Comment: Sin probar tu código se percibe el siguiente detalle: escribiste `id{{'Movements'+i}}"` debiera estar escrito `id="{{'Movements'+i}}"` de modo que los objetos con `id = 'Movements' + casilla` no están siendo tomados por  `getElementById('Movements' + casilla)`

Answer (score 0):

Bueno hay varias formas en las que puedes aplicar **disabled** (Primeramente aclararte que no es bueno que utilices **var** y en su lugar utilices **const** o **let** según requieras)
lo que debes hacer es usar **[ ]** para poder utilizar variables desde typescript y que ésta cambie cada vez que cambias el valor de *disabled*.
Ejemplo:

HTML

```
<mat-checkbox [disabled]='disabled'>
<button (click)='disabled = !disabled'>change</button>
```

TS

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public disabled = true;
    .
    .
    .
```

Otra es utilizando **ViewChild** *esto en lugar de utilizar document.getElementById* ya que esta forma es muy utilizada en JavaScript y ten en cuenta que estas trabajando con TypeScript
Aunque la forma que te mostré deberia funcionarte bien.

Espero te sirva saludos ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió esta solución, tendré en cuenta lo de const y let, esque soy algo novato usando angular jaja gracias de nuevo

Comment: Vale ahora otra pregunta, si no es mucha molestia, estoy recorriendo con ngFor los componentes porque quiero sacar varios datos, he conseguido exportar los id dinamicos (de ahi los id entre llaves), el caso es que tendría que hacer lo mismo con ese disable para que se me active y desactive el elemento segun yo quiera y luego exportarlo al TS